# How to embed a small image on top of another image and save it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, tiff

I have a large image tif format and two small images.

What I wanted to achieve is that I want to embed either of the two small images on top of a large image and save it using JavaScript.

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <img src="largeimg" />
        <p>Select the image to embed on the large image</p>
        <img src="smallimg1" />
        <img src="smallimg2" />
    </body>
 </html>
```

Is there any way to achieve the above using javascript?

Comment: Interesting... I know of PHP image manipulation libraries, but I've never seen one in JavaScript. Be curious to see if such a thing exists, too.

Comment: As Javascript is clientside, you can't save anything like this. You'll need to do some work in php or flash too.

Comment: OptimusCrime has a good point :). Image files can be stored on the client (e.g. using localstorage), but definitely not saved to a file somewhere on the disk automatically - user will have to do the saving manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the images are on the same origin the it is possible to use canvas.

- draw images to `canvas`
- call [`canvas.toDataURL()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) to retrieve the image data
- create `img` element and append data to it

### Example:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="main" src="image1" />
<img class="small" src="image2" data-posx="0" data-posy="0" />
<img class="small" src="image3" data-posx="50" data-posy="50" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function process(main, rest) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = main.width;
  canvas.height = main.height;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(main, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < rest.length; i++) {
    var img = rest[i];
    ctx.drawImage(img, img.getAttribute("data-posx"), img.getAttribute("data-posy"));
  }

  return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = process(document.getElementById("main"),  document.getElementsByClassName("small"));
document.getElementById("result").appendChild(img);
```

If you want to write the image on `[0, 0]` coordinates then you don't have to use `data-` attributes, of course. Problem with this approach is that if the files are hosted on different origin then `toDataURL` will throw security error.

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/1011582

*Note:* I would like to link jsfiddle or jsbin example but because of the same origin policy I cannot create any reasonably looking example. Any ideas?

**[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/TuSU9/)** is the best example I was able to get (tested with Chrome & FF).